# How do i know in the detail view what cell in tableview was selected?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

how can i know what tableview cell was selected?(being in the detail view)
The problem is that.
I have an table view controller. Here are parsed from the internet entries to the table.
So it's a dynamic tabe view that loads from internet. I will not know how many entries will be in the table so i will not know what details view to call when i click a row.
So i have maked one view. This view contains an calendar. On this calendar(wich is the detail iew) i will parse data from internet depending on the selected row.
For exemple: i have table: entry 1, entry 2,entry 3,entry 4
When i click entry 2 i need to call a php with the argument entry 2. The php will know what entry on the table i have selected and will generate me the correct xml that i will parse.

Here is my tableview didSelectRow function:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Navigation logic -- create and push a new view controller

 if(bdvController == nil)
    bdvController = [[BookDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BookDetailView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
  Villa *aVilla = [appDelegate.villas objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

  [self.navigationController pushViewController:bdvController animated:YES]
```

And here is my self view function on detailviewcontroller:

```
-(void)loadView {

    [super loadView];

    self.title=@"Month"

    UIBarButtonItem *addButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"ListView" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(add:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButtonItem;

    calendarView = [[[KLCalendarView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f,  320.0f, 373.0f) delegate:self] autorelease];
    appDelegate1 = (XMLAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    myTableView=[[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 260, 320, 160)style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    myTableView.dataSource=self;
    myTableView.delegate=self;
    UIView *myHeaderView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, myTableView.frame.size.width,2)];
    myHeaderView.backgroundColor=[UIColor grayColor];
    [myTableView setTableHeaderView:myHeaderView];

    [self.view addSubview:myTableView];
    [self.view addSubview:calendarView];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:myTableView];
}
```

I think that here in self load i need to make the if procedure..
If indexPath.row=x  parse fisier.php?variabila=title_of_rowx
but the question is how i know the indexPath variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a property on BookDetailViewController:

BookDetailViewController.h:

```
@interface BookDetailViewController : UITableViewController {
    NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath;
@end
```

BookDetailViewController.m

```
@implementation BookDetailViewController
@synthesize selectedIndexPath;
- (void)dealloc {
    [selectedIndexPath release];
}
// ...
@end
```

tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Navigation logic -- create and push a new view controller

    if(bdvController == nil) {
        bdvController = [[BookDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BookDetailView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    }
    bdvController.selectedIndexPath = indexPath
    Villa *aVilla = [appDelegate.villas objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:bdvController animated:YES]
}
```

Depending on what you're doing in your application it may make more sense to make the property a Villa object rather than an NSIndexPath.